# HP Proliant ML350 Gen9 Server with Debian Linux Kernel Does not boot HBA mode SAS drives. initramfs timeout. long disk detection. disks not recognized

Tags: linux, timeout, hba, initramfs

This is what I have:

1- HP Proliant ML350 Gen9 with SAS LFF (3.5 inch) Disks running in HBA mode.

2- Debian Linux version 10 (Buster) Kernel Does not boot HBA mode SAS drives normaly. I have to go to recovery mode in order to boot then press ctrl+D to proceed to normal booting.

3- In normal boot with systemd mode, I get initramfs timeout. long disk detection. However, the boot disks not recognized.

4- Some kernel versions do boot on normal systemd mode, some others don't. I had kernel 4.9.0-8 was able to boot with the following GRUB Linux kernel options, whereas on a vanilla kernel 5.8.9 compiled using the Debian way it does not boot and initramfs times out. I compiled the kernel in order to set it to run for server instead for desktop.

```
#You can find this line in /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet pci=nomsi,noaer log_buf_len=50M"
```

I used the rootdelay=30 linux kernel option according to the link below it did not work.

[Increase disk detection timeout at boot with Linux/Systemd](https://serverfault.com/questions/938506/increase-disk-detection-timeout-at-boot-with-linux-systemd)

then I changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to the following and the server booted:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootdelay=30 quiet  log_buf_len=50M"
```

I all i need is someone tell me what exactly happened. why did the sever boot?

Comment: Why are you avoiding RAID mode for your OS?

Comment: I used RAID before.  But i better go HBA.  I have 4 disks . RAID does not save a file if it was deleted by mistake. A RAID array is just similar to one USB flash drive. it's one container. RAID does help in making the system keep on going, but it does not save the files in case of deletion by mistake. I  do daily backup. so what I did is changed RIAD10 to HBA and made  disk-1 for booting linux, disk-2 for server data which is shared. I do rsync copy  every hour using cron from disk-2 to disk-3 and disk-4 . This way I always guarantee the safety of my files, and  I can easily restore them.

Comment: also I have to add I am not discussing RAID.

Comment: This is bad information.

Comment: Question aside, this is faulty reasoning as online backups (backups accessible) are not backups at all - your data should be in *another location* protected from deletion or loss. If you're looking to protect data against e.g. accidental deletion there are better proven ways to accomplish that, e.g. ZFS. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific feature or reason for upgrading the kernel, then use the distribution kernel which you have already discovered works.

If you *really* want to compile the kernel yourself (an unnecessary micro-optimization, IMO) then compile it from the distribution source package.